# Laravel 9 serializeDate() Not Working on Other Columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I want to return json wit all the data with a timestamp datatype turned into ISO 8601 automatically. This should be easily achievable after Laravel 7 but I still face the issue.

I have created two columns `start_time` and `end_time` with the `timestamp` data type. While returning the results in JSON, Laravel only converts `created_at` and `updated_at` into ISO8601 (e.g. **2022-04-26T09:44:47.000000Z**). The two columns I created are returned as they are stored in the database (e.g. **2022-01-17 19:45:07**).

Anything I added in `serializeDate()` to replace the default method would only affect `created_at` and `updated_at`.

The closest I can get is to add below to my model, but it still has a slight difference in format (e.g. **2022-04-26T10:30:00Z** vs **2022-04-26T09:44:47.000000Z**).

```
protected $casts = [
        'start_time' => 'date:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',
        'end_time' => 'date:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',

    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because you need to tell Laravel about the columns it should consider as dates in your model, by default **created_at** and **updated_at** are considered.

There is a protected property called **$dates**, it takes an array of all the columns to be considered as dates. the serializeDate method looks after that property.

```
protected $dates = [
    'reception_date',
    'response_date' ,
    '...'
];


protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    // you may give whatever format you want
    return $date->translatedFormat('d M Y à H:i');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the questions directly but I found a workaround. What you can do is `Carbon::parse` those columns returned as stored in the database before returning them in Json.

Here is an example if you are returning all the slots in your database:

```
foreach ($slots as $slot) {
     $slot->start = Carbon::parse($slot->start_time);
     $slot->end = Carbon::parse($slot->end_time);
}

return response()->json($slots);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can cast columns to `date` and `serializeDate()` function  will automatically cast your date columns

```
use DateTimeInterface;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'start_time' => 'date',
        'end_time' => 'date',
    ];

    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```